# How to get a number of particular value of each variable in data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame `all_vars_ready_2016`. I want to get number of particular value (for example, number of `NA` values) for each variable that is in `all_vars_ready_2016` data frame. How can I do it?

Comment: Not a duplicate! My question is about "number of particular value of each variable in data frame". Question that is people think is similar is about "sum of all values in every column in data frame". They are different.

Comment: @NelsonGon, please read my comment above.

Comment: @akrun please read my comment above.

Comment: @akrun The second link counts all NA values in one variable of data frame. My question asks about  NA counts for each variable in data frame, not one particular (as in link)

Comment: Have you checked the answer by TonyLadson in the link `df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,NA), y = rep(NA, 3))

colSums(is.na(df))`

Comment: If you concider the `colSums(is.na(df))` is different from the answer here, I can reopen

Comment: Do you think it is not a dupe?

Comment: @akrun First of all I asked not only for `NA` value count (please see my question and answer that was accepted). Second the answer TonyLadson answer my question if I need to check for NA value but not for other values (I asked for other values too). I think it is related but not duplicate.

Comment: @akrun I accepted correct answer because it fully answer my question. Answer that I have accepted answers "How to get a number of particular value of each variable in data frame ". TonyLadson answer  answers on "How to get a number of NA values of each variable in data frame". So the answers are different.

Comment: I added one more link.  If you really think that `colSums(df == 5)` and `colSums(is.na(df))` should correctly match, I reopen it

Comment: @akrun With last link that you have provided I agree that it is duplicate (only together link 2 and 3 answer my question). Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For checking `NA` value:

```
colSums(is.na(all_vars_ready_2016))
```

For checking other values, for example number of `5`s in each variable in data frame:

```
colSums(all_vars_ready_2016==5)
```

Comment: What about if I want to check number of other values? For example number of `5`s in each variable in data frame?

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply`:

```
apply(data, 2, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
```